# Pandas: Recursively search parent and child columns to get all children

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I have a (very large) data set where I do not know how many "levels"/deep the relationship between parent and child is. I do know that I need to:

1. For every item that we look for, find the set of values found in the `related` column.  `related_child = df.loc[df['source'] == 'A']['related'].values`
2. For every value returned in step 1, assume these are parents and look for their children in the `related` values: `df.loc[df['source'].isin(related_child )]['related'].values`
3. Repeat 2 until no more children are found, each time assuming that the values we find in `related` must be parents themselves and have children.

I am having trouble with dealing uniqueness such that it does not keep returning the same findings, but understands that it found that child already and will not keep searching it and logically exhaust itself.

```
# toy example of the data set
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['A', 'A' ,'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                    'related': ['C', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'F', 'A']
                    })
```

How can I quickly traverse my data frame while recording all the children found?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: How can `'A'` be a source for `'B'` and related to `'B'` ? Also what kind of data structure are you intending to use to store the parent child relationships?

Comment: sounds like you really want a network graph and not a dataframe